# Web Automation with Web Browser control called from a WebService

Tags: wcf, web-services, webbrowser-control

I am working on a project that needs to use the Web Browser control to simulate a user on a website so they can fill out a form and get the results back from it.

I have the code working in a console app and would like to call the console app from a web service. The reason behind this is the potential volume of requests and the ability to pass parameters to the console app.

Does this sounds viable and are there any caveats to this approach such as a limiting factor to how many calls I can make to the console app, etc.

Comment: Create a web service from the existing web site where the user fills out the form. Call that service from your website.

Comment: do you mean you want to spawn the console app from a service or that the functionality that is currently in the console app you want to turn into a service?

Comment: I would like to execute the console app from the web service as I could run several 'jobs' at once. I am trying to figure out the performance limits and if this way is even optimal.

Comment: Why even have an intermediate application? Once a web site needs to be used by another web site, the first site should be made into a web service.

Comment: You can multiplex multiple operations using threads - unless you need a high degree of isolation (e.g. different security context) then why spawn a separate process?

Comment: Richard,

Isolation isn't needed. Here's a possible scenario...100 web service calls within a minute and each call could require 2 requests to the console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webbrowser control (and some old versions of Google Chrome for Windows, by the way) uses WinInet as its networking layer, and [WinInet is not supported in Windows Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238425), such running under IIS.

Webbrowser control requires STA, which is not suitable for ASP.net.

Webbrowser control loads a lot of dll files, so you may need to run ProcMon on the server to see which file/folder you need to give permission to the ASP.Net user.

Webbrowser leaks a lot, it does not scale well on servers.

I remember seeing people moved from the webbrowser control from IE to GeckoFX, then to WebKit.Net for Windows service, but I have not heard back from anyone moving to WebKit. I don't know if anyone tried using CefSharp to run Chromium in Windows Services, but it is worth a try, Chromium switched to its own network stack a while ago.